# Extend Classes in Template (D)

Tags: class, templates, d

How do I extend a class that's inside a template in D?

```
template A {
    abstract class B {}
}
class C : B {}
```

How so I extend B, from outside A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, you need to specify template arguments.

```
a.d:3: parenthesized TemplateParameterList expected following TemplateIdentifier
```

I'm not sure if you want `C` to be a template too.
The following outputs `0`.

```
import std.stdio;

template A(T) {
  abstract class  B {
    public T f() {
      return T.init;
    } 
  }
}

class C : A!(int).B {}

int main() {
  writeln((new C()).f());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know it doesn't compile, I was just trying to clarify what I meant. :P
 Thanks for your help!